# How to prove that this geometric constructions for the pythagorean means are right?

Tags: geometry, means

According to wikipedia the Pythagorean means (and the quadratic one) of two numbers can be constructed geometrically in this way:
[image: pytagorean means]

While the arithmetic mean it's obvious, and I think I understood the construction of GM, I cannot clearly see why this construction works for HM and QM, can someone give me an hint on how to prove the correctness of this construction?

Thanks in advance

Alessandro

Comment: Note that the blue line divides the radius $A=(b+a)/2$ into $b$ and $(b+a)/2-b=(a-b)/2$. What does the Pythagorean theorem tell you about $Q$ (and $G$, for that matter)? For $H$, take note of the various similar triangles present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By similarity of triangles $\frac{A}{G} = \frac{G}{H}$ so $H=\frac{G^2}{A}=\frac{2ab}{a+b}$ is the harmonic mean.

$$Q^2 = A^2+ \left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$$

So:

$$Q=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}$$ is the quadratic mean (or root mean square.)

Comment: As I think of it, I wonder what other power means of $a$ and $b$ are constructible. (I doubt irrational power means are possible, but I'm not certain all rational ones can be done either.)

Comment: I would suspect that not all powers can be with anything "constructible" because you can't compute general cube roots with straight edge and compass. So, for example, $\sqrt[3]3=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1^3+2^3}{3}}$ cannot be constructed without something more complicated than a straight edge and compass. @Semiclassical

Comment: @Semiclassical If you want to ask another question, feel free to. Comments are not meant for chatting, but for clarification of questions and answers.